# CoffeeScript can't use spread operator with class fields

Tags: syntax, coffeescript, syntax-error, webstorm

I can't understand why this syntax of spread method is wrong for CoffeeScript in WebStorm

```
class Test
 fruit: {apple: "apple"}
 
 init: ->
     console.log 1, @fruit
     
 spread: ->
     console.log 2, {@fruit...}
     
 spreadWithVar: ->
     fruit = @fruit
     console.log 3, {fruit...}

test = new Test()

test.init()
test.spread()
test.spreadWithVar()
```

After compiling I get this JS code:

```js
(function() {
  var Test, test;

  Test = (function() {
    class Test {
      init() {
        return console.log(1, this.fruit);
      }

      spread() {
        return console.log(2, {...this.fruit});
      }

      spreadWithVar() {
        var fruit;
        fruit = this.fruit;
        return console.log(3, {...fruit});
      }

    };

    Test.prototype.fruit = {
      apple: "apple"
    };

    return Test;

  }).call(this);

  test = new Test();

  test.init();

  test.spread();

  test.spreadWithVar();

}).call(this);
1 { apple: 'apple' }
2 { apple: 'apple' }
3 { apple: 'apple' }
```

To run code and see result in online compiler: [jdoodle.com/ia/qQh](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/qQn)

All three methods work fine when it compiled and give to me an expected JavaScript code. But as in online editor in WebStorm I get errors about of syntax `@name...`:

[image]

and

[image]

And I can not understand why? If it gives to me a correct JavaScript code, why does it think that this is wrong for CoffeeScript?

Comment: This compiles and runs fine for me. Using webpack with `coffee-loader` 0.9 and `coffeescript` 2.3.2. Maybe you have an older version of coffeescript?

Comment: @caffeinated.tech Yes I use coffee 2.7.0. And as I said before it works. I mean it give to me a correct JS code after compiling but it show me an syntax error when compiling in Gulp and also show syntax error in WebStorm

Comment: Is there a particular linter you are using? Could you copy over your gulp config? Maybe it's a webstorm thing too, I use SublimeText 3 so couldn't debug that.

Comment: No we aren't using linter. For coffee script files we are using `gulp-coffee` npm package

Comment: I don't know if it will have an impact on errors shown by webstorm, but you could try `gulp-babel` instead of `gulp-coffee` which hasn't been updated in a while

Comment: @caffeinated.tech After updating my `gulp-coffee` the error from gulp disappeared and it compiles perfectly. But in WebStorm it shows me the syntax error `"AssignObj" expected` when I navigate mouse to red underline and that is all. No explanation what does it except instead of. I tried to replace `@` with `this.` but it didn't help. I will update my question

Answer (score 0):

As you fixed your errors in gulp by updating `gulp-coffee` to the latest version, I think the webstorm problem is likely to have a similar solution.

Looking at the [webstorm coffeescript](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/coffeescript.html#ws_coffee_installation) documentation, they mention that it depends on a globally installed `coffeescript` package.

First check if your global coffeescript is outdated:

```
npm outdated -g --depth=0
```

Then you can go ahead and update it:

```
npm update -g coffeescript
```

Comment: Sorry but it isn't works for me. I [did this instruction](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/coffeescript.html#ws_coffee_installation) and [this instruction](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/coffeescript.html#ws_coffee_compilation_create_fw) after this I remove all project indexes and file system cache and restart my WebStorm. If it matters I'm working on Fedora and have the last version of WebStorm

Comment: `npm list -g` shows to me `coffeescript@2.7.0`. Also I installed it globally with `sudo` and it installed in `/usr/local/lib`. May be it must in `/home/user_name`? But `npm list -g` looks in `/usr/local/lib`